# FFmpeg Android concat. "–safe 0" is an invalid argument

Tags: android, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am trying to append two .mp4 videos on Android. Following an unsafe file name error with command:

```
String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-f", "concat", "-i", list, "-c", "copy", outputFilePath};
```

I added the string "–safe 0" as recommended on FFmpeg documentation:

```
String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-f", "concat","–safe 0", "-i", list, "-c", "copy", outputFilePath};
```

However, FFmpeg does not recognise the command, giving this error message:

```
Failure with output
 ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
 Unrecognized option ‘–safe 0'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

I have tried various permutations with the type of dash (–) and (-), used, but still get an error. Sometimes, using a certain dash or no dash at all returns a slightly different error message:

```
Failure with output
I/System.out: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
I/System.out:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
I/System.out:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
I/System.out:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
 Input #0, tty, from '/data/user/0/com.example.cameraapp2/cache/ffmpeg-list1251307830.txt':

Duration: 00:00:00.04, bitrate: 28 kb/s
     Stream #0:0: Video: ansi, pal8, 640x400, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
 [NULL @ 0xed834600] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
 ffmpeg: Invalid argument
```

However, amendments I make there (such as removing `"ffmpeg"`) haven't resolved the issue.

String `list` is the absolute path of a textfile, generated with code I have copied written by user Marc Plano-Lesay:

```
private static String generateList(String[] inputs) {
    File list;
    Writer writer = null;
    try {
        list = File.createTempFile("ffmpeg-list", ".txt");
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(list)));
        for (String input: inputs) {
            writer.write("file '" + input + "'\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "/";
    } finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and here are relevant code snippets that refers to it:

```
inputFilePath1 = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/VID_20200416_162058.mp4";
inputFilePath2 = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/VID_20200418_104909.mp4";
```

`String list = generateList(new String[] {inputFilePath1, inputFilePath2});`

Android can usually find the input files just fine, so I'm not sure what's left to try. The error messages above confirm my assumption that I'm running FFmpeg 0.3.1 which should be recent enough.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the option and value i.e. `"–safe", "0"`

Comment: I probably [found a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362471/wrong-framerate-during-ffmpeg-concatenation) in `concat`. Can you please comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hyphen, not a dash.

Correct: `-safe`
Incorrect: `–safe`