# Wrong framerate during FFMPEG concatenation

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4, video-processing

I'm concatenating 2 video files [00000](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vzzb25hv1qza81o/00000.mp4) and [00001](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9bgvjedm6c1lrys/00001.mp4):

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i file_list.txt -loglevel error -c copy test.mp4

file_list.txt:
file '00000.mp4'
file '00001.mp4'

00000.mp4:
Duration: 00:00:00.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 204 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 182 kb/s,
60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)

00001.mp4:
Duration: 00:00:01.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 58 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 48 kb/s,
60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
```

The result has a different framerate:

```
test.mp4:
Duration: 00:00:02.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 85 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 76 kb/s,
59.99 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
```

How can I keep the framerate of the files constant?

I checked for a VFR:

```
ffmpeg -i 00000.mp4 -vf vfrdet -an -f null -
VFR:0.000000 (0/24)

ffmpeg -i 00001.mp4 -vf vfrdet -an -f null -
VFR:0.000000 (0/97)

ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf vfrdet -an -f null -
VFR:0.016393 (2/120) min: 256 max: 261 avg: 258
```

Is it possible to get `VFR:0` after the concatenation?

Comment: The frame rate has not  changed. It is just a rounding error.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. When I concat more than 2 clips It sometimes shows 59.94.

Comment: Verify with `ffprobe -select_streams v -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate,avg_frame_rate,time_base,duration,nb_frames test.mp4`

Comment: Thank you @szatmary and @llogan. I got `avg_frame_rate=1889280/31493` for `test.mp4` and `avg_frame_rate=60/1` for both input files. It is a variable framerate in `test.mp4`. How can I get CFR instead of VFR after the concatenation? See updated question.